# How to execute specific test method in junit 4.8.x

Tags: java

I want to write java code which executes specific test method of junit 4.8.x test class.
For instance, in junit 3.8.x, to execute a particular test method, we write following chunk of code:

```
TestResult res = junit.textui.TestRunner.run(junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest((Class< ? extends TestCase>)className, methodName));
```

Here, className is subclass of TestCase and MethodName is test method defined in className.
It executes "methodName" test method and save results in "res".
In the same manner, I want to execute a particular test method for junit 4.8.x class also.
Can somebody tell me the answer...

Comment: I would use JUnit 4.10. What happened when you tried this? AFAIK, its the same.

Comment: The createTest() api requires a subclass of TestCase whereas in case of junit 4.8.x we dont extend any class. We just annotate every test method with @Test. I have to use junit 4.8.x version only as this is the only version approved in my organization.

Comment: An approved way to use the library would have been more useful ;)

Comment: Can you please help me with working code?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the cast to TestCase if you are not using a TestCase.

In JUnit 4.10 TestSuite.createTest(Class theClass, String name) will take any class.

If I look at the source for TestSuite in 4.10

https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/junit/framework/TestSuite.java

```
public class TestSuite implements Test {

/**
 * ...as the moon sets over the early morning Merlin, Oregon
 * mountains, our intrepid adventurers type...
 */
static public Test createTest(Class<?> theClass, String name) {
    Constructor<?> constructor;
    try {
        constructor= getTestConstructor(theClass);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        return warning("Class "+theClass.getName()+" has no public constructor TestCase(String name) or TestCase()");
    }
    Object test;
    try {
        if (constructor.getParameterTypes().length == 0) {
            test= constructor.newInstance(new Object[0]);
            if (test instanceof TestCase)
                ((TestCase) test).setName(name);
        } else {
            test= constructor.newInstance(new Object[]{name});
        }
```

In this version it will take any type.

Comment: even in JUnit 4.x also, createTest(class, String name) takes subclass of TestCase. The parameter types for createTest is createTest(Class<? extends TestCase> theClass, String name). I want an API which creates test by taking any class, not only subclass of TestCase.

Comment: Perhaps is something 4.8 can't do, but 4.10 can.